# Is it possible to turn all html images into links via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to turn every `<img>` into a link to itself (the file) via an external js file.

My thought process was that I could target all img elements, then grab the image src and place a link to it around the img element.
For example:

Turning this:

```
<img width="281" vspace="7" hspace="5" height="215" align="left" alt="img1" src="cits/images/image001.jpg"></img>
```

Into this:

```
<a href="cits/images/image001.jpg" target="_blank">
<img width="281" vspace="7" hspace="5" height="215" align="left" alt="img1" src="cits/images/image001.jpg"></img>
</a>
```

It looks like I can grab the img src as a variable as well as find the img element, but I'm not sure how I could go about adding the link around the img.

Comment: I'd use another approach: handle clicks on all the images as if they are links (using `window.open`, if you want them to be opened in the separate window). The problem is, wrapping all images in <a> element may disrupt the structure of your page.

Comment: @raina77ow  That sounds a lot easier, thanks. I'm going to leave this up for a bit incase anyone has more ideas to throw out or solutions.

Comment: @ Richard Dalton No, I'm only using javascript right now. I'm open to jquery, but I'm new to js, haven't done much in jquery.

Answer (score 3):

Grab all your images.

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
```

Write a function that replaces the `outerHTML` of an image with new markup, including a link pointing to the `src` attribute of the image, which includes the old `outerHTML` of the image.

```
function makeLink(image){
    image.outerHTML = '<a target="_blank" href="' + image.src + '">' + image.outerHTML + '</a>';
}
```

Loop through your images, and submit each one to the `makeLink` function.

```
for(var i = 0, l = images.length; i < l; ++i){
    makeLink(images[i]);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you are using jQuery

```
$('img').each(function(ix, image){
  $(image).wrap('<a target="_blank" href="' + $(image).attr('src') + '"></a>');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use `jQuery`, the code is very simple:

```
$("img").each(function () {
    $(this).wrap($("<a target='_blank'/>").attr("href", $(this).attr("src"));
});
```

Otherwise you're gonna have to look into a raw `JavaScript` solution, which is a bit more elaborate. See @Barney's answer.